# Pivot Tables: how can I stop my columns from disappearing if they are empty?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, formatting, pivot-table

I've ticked 'preserve cell formatting on update', but if one of the columns doesn't have an entry then it disappears. Is there any way I can keep it from disappearing even if it's blank? I suspect not because of the nature of Pivot Tables, but it's worth asking.

I have 6 columns - 3 No's and 3 Yes's. I only need the Yes's to appear in the PT, so I select them, and it all works fine while there is something in the Yes column. However, when the soucre table doesn't have a Yes in it then the appropriate column disappears.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Michael.

Comment: Not sure I understand the layout of your data.  Can you provide a sample?